# how to change the default redirect page of a url in sitemap in another page in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have two home pages which is different for users and admin. For users its Default.aspx and for admin its AdminDefault.aspx. In my Site.Master page it contains the default url for home page and other default pages as below,

```
<ul id="menu">
     <li><a runat="server" id="home" href="~/">Home</a></li>
     <li><a runat="server" href="~/About.aspx">About</a></li>
     <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

When a admin logges in, the admin redirect to the default home page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you have the following function to determine wether a user is a member of the administrator group

```
bool IsInGroup(string user, string group)
{
    using (var identity = new WindowsIdentity(user))
    {
        var principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
        return principal.IsInRole(group);
    }
}
```

It is then a simple matter of redirecting after an IF statement, like so:

```
if(IsInGroup(User.Name, "Administrators")
    return RedirectToAction("AdminDefault.aspx");
```

(Mind you the code example above is written from memory, and may not be exact. In fact, it probably isnt)

Answer (score 1):

```
Check Role Using session and provide condition like this


    string Role="";

    on Login button click event check the role

   YourLoginMethod()
   {
      // Your Login Code and after check
     //Pass Role in string above or Use session
     if(Role=="admin")
     {
     Response.Redirect("~/Admin.aspx");
    }
    else{
     Response.Redirect("~/Index.aspx");
    }
   }
```